# Body parser undefined, req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

So i have this Post route to add some products to my MongoDB

```
router.post('/addprod',mid.reqAdmin,function(req,res,next){
            if(req.body.category && req.body.name && req.body.price && req.body.description && req.files)
            {
                upload(req,res,function(err) {
                    console.log("req.body"); //form fields
                    console.log(req.body);
                    console.log("req.file");
                    console.log(req.files); //form files
                })
                var prodData={
                    name: req.body.name,
                    price: req.body.price,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    category: req.body.category,    
                    images: req.files.filename
                };
                console.log(prodData);
                Prod.create(prodData,function (error, product) {
                    if (error) {
                        req.flash('error','Error');
                        return res.redirect('/addprod');
                    } 
                    else{
                        req.flash('success', 'Success');
                        return res.redirect('/addprod');
                    }
                });         
            }else
            {
                req.flash('error','All Fields Required');
                return res.redirect('/addprod');
            }
        });
```

And i have this (pug/jade) template:

```
.form
        form(enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/addprod' method='POST')
            input(type="text"  id='category' placeholder="Category name='category')
            input(type="text"  id='name' placeholder="Name" name='name')
            input(type="text"  id='price' placeholder="Price" name='price')
            input(type="text"  id='description' placeholder="Description" name='description')
            input(type="file" name="images" multiple)
            button(type="submit") Add
```

So when i click Add button with all fields filled i get "All fields required"
i put some console logs before IF statement and i get req.body.name = undefined
and req.body = {}. And i don't know why i get that. 
In app.js file i have body parser. I mean in every route but this body parser works.

Comment: `body-parser` doesn't handle `multipart/form-data.` You need `multer` / `formidable` npm package for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) doesn't handle `multipart/form-data`. You need [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) / [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) or similar npm package for this.

Example with [express-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable):

**somewhere in express configuration**

```
// ...

const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable');

//...

app.use(formidableMiddleware({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  multiples: true
});

// ...
```

Then in your controller file you can use `req.fields` to access text-fields (e.g. `category`, `name`) and `req.files` to access binary data (e.g `images`)

**Example**:

```
router.post('/addprod', mid.reqAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.fields.category &&
       req.fields.name &&
       req.fields.price &&
       req.fields.description &&
       req.files) {
      // ...
    } else {
      // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using Multer for that body request and i am still getting undefinded